# Android: java.io.FileNotFoundException even though file can be viewed on browser

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to download an image file within my app but I keep getting "java.io.FileNotFoundException" even though I can view the image on my browser. Here is the code that suppose to download the file. You could test the link on browser

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                String sample = "https://yande.re/image/617a7bff242f2ec56ccfc84df53604fc/yande.re%20263544%20chibi%20shinomiya_himawari%20vividred_operation.jpg";
                try
                {   
                  URL url = new URL(sample);
                  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
                  urlConnection.connect();                  


                  File SDCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Yandere/Wallpapers");
                  SDCardRoot.mkdirs();
                  String filename="downloadedFile.jpg";   
                  Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
                  File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
                  if(file.createNewFile())
                  {
                    file.createNewFile();
                  }                 
                  FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                  int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                  int downloadedSize = 0;   
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                  int bufferLength = 0;
                  while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
                  {                 
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
                    Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
                  }             
                  fileOutput.close();
                  if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath=file.getPath();    
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                  filepath=null;
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }}
        }).start();
```

Error:

```
 08-05 16:36:28.032: W/System.err(17064): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://yande.re/image/617a7bff242f2ec56ccfc84df53604fc/yande.re%20263544%20chibi%20shinomiya_himawari%20vividred_operation.jpg
08-05 16:36:28.032: W/System.err(17064):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
08-05 16:36:28.032: W/System.err(17064):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
08-05 16:36:28.032: W/System.err(17064):    at angel.util.Downloader$1.run(Downloader.java:52)
08-05 16:36:28.032: W/System.err(17064):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace please

Comment: What happens if you change HTTPS to plain old HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Url string from :

"https://yande.re/image/617a7bff242f2ec56ccfc84df53604fc/yande.re%20263544%20chibi%20shinomiya_himawari%20vividred_operation.jpg"

to

"http://yande.re/image/617a7bff242f2ec56ccfc84df53604fc/yande.re%20263544%20chibi%20shinomiya_himawari%20vividred_operation.jpg"

Actually changing "https" to "http" and it should work. It is working for me with this change.

Comment: Changing it to "http" actually bypasses the error but the downloaded file is empty..

Comment: For me, I am getting 184kb download. Just remove and reconnect your device to make mediascanner run. or can give a restart to phone and then check..

Comment: Yep that one. I think this is a limitation from their server. I switched to using a DownloadManager class in android. It's working fine. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can accept my answer if you feel it solved your purpose, so that others can refer to this answer in future.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use following HTTP GET request method. It seems the HTTP POST not supported by your web server.

```
 urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are `POST`ing to that URL in the code and not `GET`ing it.
That results in the server returning a `405 Method Not Allowed` error. If you use `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");` as Shamim Ahmmed suggets then you should be able to get the file you want.

You can read more about the different request methods [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). Basically, `POST` is normally used when you want to send data to the server and `GET` is used when you're just trying to get data from the server. In the case of the image, the server isn't configured to be able to handle a `POST` request for it and just returns back an HTML error page instead of the image that you were expecting.